# Run bash command on writing a file with a particular extension?

Tags: save, autocmd, linux, bash

I want to run a bash command on writing a `.less` file, saving it and generating the corresponding `.css` file with the same name and in the same directory. I do have the bash command which generates the `.css` file.

I'm not used to vimscript except for working with vim and changing some stuff in my `.vimrc`, so I'm not sure how to get this to work.

To sum it up:

- How do I run a bash command on `:w`?
- How do I get the current file directory (vimscript or bash)?
- How do I get the current file name (vimscript or bash)?

Comment: Don't do that in Vim, use a watcher instead like Grunt/Brunch/Gulp.

Comment: Related: http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/258/how-do-i-run-a-command-on-creation-of-a-new-file

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use autocommands to run things automatically when certain events occur.  In your case, you could do this:

```
autocmd BufWritePost *.less !less <afile>
```

This autocommand runs every time a buffer with a name that ends in `.less` is written.  The command that is being run is a bash command, and `<afile>` is the name of the file that is being written.  Essentially, the `!` command allows you to run bash commands in vim.

Relevant help topics:

- `:help :autocmd`
- `:help BufWritePost`
- `:help :!`
- `:help <afile>`

#### NOTE

Vim doesn't automatically refresh the screen when a bash command is run.  See the below answer for information on that:
[Suppress output from a vim autocomand](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3060/suppress-output-from-a-vim-autocomand/3062#3062)